# Sectioning plane tool wrong position on restore state

Tags: autodesk-viewer

When I save a state and restore it, the sectioning plane goes to the right position. However, when I activate the sectioning tool (for moving the planes), it keeps in the current position (the one before restoring the state). In this case, the "hatch" gets out of the geometry (picture attached) and if I try to move the restored secioting plane, firstly it goes to the tool position, only then I can move it. So, it gets very boring to edit a restored sectioning tool. This issue happens on BIM360Docs too. To reproduce this issue, please follow these steps:

1. activate and move a section tool
2. Save the state of the viewer
3. move sectioning tool to another position
4. Restore the saved state
5. [This is what you get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wajjT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Viewer Version 6.6 was release today with a possible fix for your workflow. Can you test and let us know if all works? https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v-66